# How to use conditions on value in all rows of a R datatable

Tags: r, data.table, sapply

I have been struggling with, I think, a basic task in R but I am still new in that and couldn't achieve that with the forums I found.

Here is my dataset:

> ```
>        Read SNP.mapped DEL.mapped INS.mapped SNP.true DEL.true INS.true       Method Population
>    1:    0          0          0          0        0        0        0 E_B1    E     
>    2:    1          0          0          0        0        0        0 E_B1    E     
>    3:  100          0          0          0        0        0        0 E_B1    E     
>    4: 1000          0          0          0        0        0        0 E_B1    E     
>    5: 100B          0          0          0        0        0        0 E_B1    E     
>    ...
>    30657866:  ZZ2          0          0          0        0        0     0 C_N9    C     
>    30657867:  ZZI          0          0          0        0        0     0 C_N9    C     
>    30657868:  ZZO          0          0          0        1        0     0 C_N9    C     
>    30657869:  ZZV          0          0          0        0        0     0 C_N9    C     
>    30657870:  ZZZ          0          0          0        0        0     0 C_N9    C
> ```

Here is the example of what I want to achieve for the first row on my datable called "all.dataSNP0" :

```
length(unique(all.dataSNP0$Read[which(all.dataSNP0$Population =="C" & all.dataSNP0$Method =="C_B1")])) / length(unique(all.dataSNP0$Read[which(all.dataSNP0$Population=="C")]))
```

The results is what I expect and works perfectly fine. However now I am trying to apply this line to all column but I don't know how to use the actual value of the column in the conditions when I loop through it. I tried to do so:

```
all.dataSNP0[, Ratio:=sapply(length(unique(all.dataSNP0$Read[which(Population == .Population & Method == .Method)])) / length(unique(all.dataSNP0$Read[which(Population== .Population)])), "[",1)]
```

But it doesn't seems to work. I do think I must be not too far but can't find it,

Thanks

Eddie

Comment: Can you explain in words what you are trying to do here? It would be helpful if you could provide a small example along with expected output.

Comment: I am trying to compute the ratio of :

Number of unique reads for a specific method AND specific population / Number of unique reads for the same specific population 

And trying to loop that over to add the value next to each value. I hope it's clear enough. The output would be a value between 0 and 1 then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `uniqueN` to count number of unique values, we can do it for each unique value in `Population` and `Method` and then count the ratio for each value of `Population`.

```
library(data.table)
all.dataSNP0[, count := uniqueN(Read), .(Population, Method)]
all.dataSNP0[, count := count/sum(count), Population]
```

The same using `dplyr` can be done as :

```
library(dplyr)

all.dataSNP0 %>%
  group_by(Population, Method) %>%
  mutate(count = n_distinct(Read)) %>%
  group_by(Population) %>%
  mutate(count = count/sum(count))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Thanks to your comments I was able to compute my ratio by modifying your code a bit (My explanation wasn't clear enough):

all.dataSNP0[, count := uniqueN(Read), .(Population, Method)]
all.dataSNP0[, countpop := uniqueN(Read), .(Population)]
all.dataSNP0[, Ratio := count/countpop]

Thanks a lot :)